# Group files in a directory based on their prefix

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a folder with pictures:

*Folder 1:*

*Files:*

```
ABC-138923
ABC-3223
ABC-33489
ABC-3111
CBA-238923
CBA-1313
CBA-1313
DAC-38932
DAC-1111
DAC-13893
DAC-23232 
DAC-9999
```

I want to go through this folder and count how many of each picture pre-fix I have.

For example, there are 4 pictures of pre-fix ABC and 3 pictures of pre-fix CBA above.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to loop through this. Anyone can give me a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a loop, but more clear and readable:

```
string[] fileNames = ...; //some initializing code
var prefixes = fileNames.GroupBy(x => x.Split('-')[0]).
    Select(y => new {Prefix = y.Key, Count = y.Count()});
```

**Upd:**

To display the count for each prefix:

```
foreach (var prefix in prefixes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Prefix: {0}, Count: {1}", prefix.Prefix, prefix.Count);
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user1336632, my fault. now fixed.

Comment: im not familiar with this code (sorry still a noobie), but how do I go about getting the count for each pre-fix to display it to the user from your code?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with a 'foreach' loop:

```
var directoryPath = ".\Folder1\";
var prefixLength = 3;
var accumulator = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath)) {
    var prefix = filefile.Replace(directoryPath, string.Empty).Substring(0, prefixLength);

    if (!accumulator.ContainsKey(prefix))
    {
        accumulator.Add(prefix, 0);
    }

    accumulator[prefix]++;
}

foreach(var prefix in accumulator.Keys) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prefix, accumulator[prefix]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm:

1. Create a dictionary:

   `Dictionary<string, int> D;`
2. Loop through the directory using:

   `foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir))
       ...`

Complete the following 3 steps for each file:

1. Extract the prefix and see if a matching key exists in `D`. If TRUE, go to step 3.
2. Insert the prefix as a new key in `D`, with value `0`
3. Increment the key's value by `1`

To display results when the entire directory has been processed:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in D)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} prefix has {1} files", pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

Comment: @user1336632 - Posted an example algorithm, you should be able to use this to implement your application.

Answer (score 0):

in C#,

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\yourfolder");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            List<string> prefix = new List<string>();
            List<int> count = new List<int>();

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                if (prefix.Count > 0)
                {
                    Boolean AddNew = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < prefix.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (file.Name.Substring(0, 3) == prefix[i])
                        {
                            count[i]++;
                            AddNew = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (AddNew)
                    {
                        prefix.Add(file.Name.Substring(0, 3));
                        count.Add(1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    prefix.Add(file.Name.Substring(0, 3));
                    count.Add(1);
                }
            }

...
```

The prefix string list is parallel to the count list, so to access you could loop through the array.   I haven't tested or optimized it, but if you're heading down this route (c#) this could be a start.