# iText FileStream overwirtes

Tags: pdf, text, itext, filestream

I am in the process of putting together some code that will merge pdf's based on the file name prefix. I currently have the below code that grabs the filename and doesn't merge, but overwrites. I believe my problem is the FileStream placement, but if I move it out of the current location, I can't get the filename. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
static void CreateMergedPDFs() 
    {
        string srcDir = "C:/PDFin/";
        string resultPDF = "C:/PDFout/";
        {
            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(srcDir);
            string prevFileName = null;

            int i = 1;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string filename = Left(Path.GetFileName(file), 8);
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(resultPDF  + filename + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
                {

                    if (prevFileName == null || filename == prevFileName)
                    {
                        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                        PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream); 
                        pdfDoc.Open();
                        {
                            pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(file));
                            i++;
                        }
                        if (pdfDoc != null)
                            pdfDoc.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine("Merges done!");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is consistent with your code. You are creating the loop in an incorrect way.

Try this:

```
static void CreateMergedPDFs() 
    {
        string srcDir = "C:/PDFin/";
        string resultPDF = "C:/PDFout/merged.pdf";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(resultPDF, FileMode.Create);
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream); 
        pdfDoc.Open();
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(srcDir);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(file));
        }
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Merges done!");
    }
}
```

That makes more sense, doesn't it?

If you want to group files based on their prefix, you should read the answer to the question [Group files in a directory based on their prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525974/group-files-in-a-directory-based-on-their-prefix)

In the answer to this question, it is assumed that the prefix and the rest of the filename are separated by a `-` character. For instance `1-abc.pdf` and `1-xyz.pdf` have the prefix `1` whereas `2-abc.pdf` and `2-xyz.pdf` have the prefix `2`. In your case, it's not clear how you'd determine the prefix, but it's easy to get a list of all the files, sort them and make groups of files based on whatever algorithm you want to determine the prefix.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have been able to merge all into a single file, my issue is creating multiple files based on the file prefix. so if I have 123.pdf, 122.pdf and 222.pdf and I want to end up with 2 pdfs in my output folder. I need the file name (prefix) before getting into the for loop so I can merge on that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your *specific* request doesn't make sense because it's not clear what the prefix would be of files named 123.pdf, 122.pdf and 222.pdf. The *general* request to filter files based on a prefix and to merge files based on that prefix makes sense, but that's a question that shouldn't be tagged as an iText question because it's kind of a no-brainer to achieve this in any programming language. I could explain how to do this in Java; you should create a C# question if you want to ask how to do it in C# (but be aware that such a question may receive down-votes).

Comment: Is this the same question that you previously deleted and then sent me an email about? Please don't send people on StackOverflow email if they haven't asked you to do so. The whole idea of StackOverflow is to do everything in public.

Comment: So the premise is the same, your just suggesting the doing the group/prefix prior to the actual pdf merge, in that way passing in the file path & prefix so as to get the desired result. Ok, I'll give it a go. I misunderstood originally. Thanks for the clarification.